# Deleting file when list view threshold is enforced

Tags: c#, preview, office365

I am trying to delete a file using the [File Rest API for Office 365](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900(v=office.15).aspx#File8)

My problem is that the view has exceeded the view threshold and there for it has certain limits. 
Normally the limit is that all operations requires paging and that is easy enough to implement when listing the files.

The think that don't make sense is that all single file requests also fail with the error:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

I tried to delete the file using different parameters, but nothing works.

> DELETE https://subdomain.sharepoint.com/_api/files('Document.docx')

And

> DELETE https://subdomain.sharepoint.com/_api/files('Document.docx')?$top=1&$take=1&top=1&take=1

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API but what's with the empty subdomain? `https://.sharepoint.com` should be `https://sharepoint.com` (no leading `.` - It could be right, but never seen a valid address that way.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to write <Subdomain> but that made the text invisible.

Comment: So far the best solution I have come up with is using the regular SharePoint 2013 Web API and only use the Authentication part of the preview.